# UITableView Editable Cell 'De-Selection'

Tags: ios, uitableview

My application has a UITableView which is editable to be able to delete items.  When a user taps the red circle on the left of the cell it reveals a red 'Delete' button.  When that 'Delete' button is tapped I am displaying a custom confirmation dialog.  If the confirmation is true then deletion proceeds normally.  If it is false I want to automatically go back to the state before the red circle was tapped.  I have tried setEditing: but it removes the circle completely.  The other two methods are setSelected: and setHighlighted:.  They don't make any change.  Is there a way to do this?